# PYTHON -INSTAGRAM Selenium

Tags: python

I have been stuck at the code from a long time:

so i want to send dm's using python on instagram but i am having a problem slecting the user from drop down menu
[like the text even goes in here, but now after this how do i select the first person?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E8huq.png)

I have tried using the find xpath method or get the class method or even tried using the button containing the text.

please help me.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select


x=input("Whom to you want to send your text message? Please type his/her name:- ")
print("Okay cool ! I got it !")
y=input("What is the message? Don't worry you can send any personal messages, I don't save them in my memory xD !")

class Instabot:
    def __init__(self, username, password):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        self.driver.get("https://instagram.com")
        sleep(2)
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name=\"username\"]")\
            .send_keys(username)
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name=\"password\"]")\
            .send_keys(password)
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@type="submit"]').click()
        sleep(3)
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[text()="Not Now"]').click()
        sleep(2)
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[text()="Not Now"]').click()
        sleep(2)
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@placeholder=\"Search\"]")\
            .send_keys(x)
        sleep(2)
        select = Select(self.driver.find_element_by_id(x))
        select.select_by_visible_text(x)
        
        sleep(1)
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[text()="Message"]').click()
        sleep(1)
        
        k=self.driver.find_element_by_tag_name('textarea')
        k.send_keys(y)
        sleep(1)
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[text()="Send"]').click()
        sleep(1)
        
        
        
        
        
Instabot("username","password",)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Full working code. This will select the first suggestion, Visit the profile page, if the message option exists, it will click on message, and send the message.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

x = input("Whom to you want to send your text message? Please type his/her name:- ")
print("Okay cool ! I got it !")
y = input("What is the message? Don't worry you can send any personal messages, I don't save them in my memory xD !")


class Instabot:
    def __init__(self, username, password):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        self.driver.get("https://instagram.com")
        sleep(2)
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name=\"username\"]") \
            .send_keys(username)
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name=\"password\"]") \
            .send_keys(password)
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@type="submit"]').click()
        sleep(3)
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[text()="Not Now"]').click()
        sleep(2)
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[text()="Not Now"]').click()
        sleep(2)
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@placeholder=\"Search\"]") \
            .send_keys(x)
        sleep(3)
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id=\"react-root\"]/section/nav/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[4]/div/a[1]/div/div[2]/div").click()
        sleep(3)


        sleep(1)
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[text()="Message"]').click()
        sleep(4)

        k = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/section/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/textarea')
        k.send_keys(y)
        sleep(1)
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[text()="Send"]').click()
        sleep(1)
```

Comment: @KartikChaudhary You need to select the `xpath` of the first suggestion and then send a `click()`. Same for the `textArea`